# Configuring custom keys on bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth

I have a Logitech Bluetooth Keyboard for Android similar to the one shown [here](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/logitech-keyboard-for-apple-ipad-2-ipad-3rd-generation-and-ipad-with-retina-black/6541921.p?id=1218752780630&skuId=6541921&ref=06&loc=01&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=6541921&extensionType=%7Badtype%7D:%7Bnetwork%7D&s_kwcid=PTC!pla!%7Bkeyword%7D!%7Bmatchtype%7D!%7Badwords_producttargetid%7D!%7Bnetwork%7D!%7Bifmobile:M%7D!%7Bcreative%7D&kpid=6541921&k_clickid=706e581e-b702-6268-7a8e-00007d308e55) at BestBuy. The one I have is older and isn't printed the same as either model shown on BestBuy's website, but it has the same number of keys in the same place.

Is there anyway I can manually map the bottom row of keys to match certain keys for Apple, such as Fn, Control, Alt/Option and Command? This would be really helpful and would let me share one bluetooth keyboard between my Android tablet and Macbook. I prefer this to a wireless keyboard is it already has a carrying case and is very light weight.

Any help is appreciated!

Mac OS X 10.9

**EDIT**
It appears, the closest to mine is now the Windows 8 RT / Android keyboard [here](http://www.logitech.com/assets/37190/tablet-keyboard-for-android-gallery-7.png), but it still doesn't have the same keyboard layout.

My keyboard has 4 buttons to the left of the space bar and 3 buttons between space and the arrows. So it has the same button positions, just different labels. Here is a pic of the one I'm using. The biggest thing is that mine doesn't have a "CMD" button, I really only need to fix the mapping so that the little search icon will act as the Apple Command button and then I would be good to go. Any ideas?

[image: my logitech keyboard layout]

** EDIT TWO **
Using the recommendation found in the accepted answer below, I started playing with the [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) and [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) software. I want to add for anyone who comes here looking for an answer to a similar problem, the two pieces of software shown above are both very good and using the instructions in the shown answer, should allow you to map any extra keys found on most keyboards. The problem with the older Logitech Android keyboard is that his software and the Macbook are apparently not recognizing those keys at all.

I appreciate all the help!

[Forum entry explained problem I experienced, by a user who tried to do this awhile back.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/keyremap4macbook/search/keyremap4macbook/IjJOs7LZGrI/rhWbbYL1dMcJ)

Comment: You post is kind of confusing because the picture has command, alt/option, and control keys already printed on it.  Maybe you should tell us exactly what your keyboard has printed in their place.

Comment: @TomG They've replaced mine at this point, so I posted an actual picture of what I'm using. Any chance you could tell me how to map that search icon button to a command button on an Apple keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download and install [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).
2. Open EventViewer:

   ```
   open /Applications/KeyRemap4MacBook.app/Contents/Applications/EventViewer.app
   ```
3. Press the key that you wish to customise and note the `KeyCode::`:

   [image]
4. Create a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <item>
       <name>Modifier Remapping</name>
       <identifier>modremap</identifier>
       <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
     </item>
   </root>
   ```

   Replace `KeyCode::CONTROL_L` with the key that you wish to change and  `KeyCode::COMMAND_L` with the key that you wish to replace it with.

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer, as I feel it answers the core problem even though my given keyboard fails to be sending in commands when pressing the search, home, back and menu keys.

Comment: @Kyle Check if you have *Don't remap external keyboards* checked in preferences, and make sure you don't have any other driver software installed for the device.

Comment: the download link is not working anymore

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE!!! To anybody who came here with a 3rd party keyboard/Mac setup but was unable to download the software above. I had this same problem. It's not a solution for remapping the entire keyboard, but if you want to just be able to remap your command/flower button, follow the instructions at the following article: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-customize-third-party-keyboard-mac/

Specifically, the following instructions:

> You can customize your external keyboard and remap certain keys by going to System Preferences > Keyboard on your Mac. It's especially important to do this if you're using a Windows keyboard to make sure the keys behave how you want them to.

> Click Change Keyboard Type to help your Mac detect what kind of keyboard you're using: Razer, Steelseries, Logitech, and so on. Follow the keyboard wizard that appears, asking you to press various keys. Based on these results, you Mac will set up the default settings for your keyboard layout.

[image]

> Click Modifier Keys to rearrange the keys that combine with others to perform certain actions. From left to right, the modifier keys on an Apple keyboard read Control, Option, Cmd whereas non-Apple keyboards usually read Control, Windows, Alt.

> By default, macOS registers the Windows key as Cmd and the Alt key as Option. So you may want to remap the modifier keys for your external keyboard to match Apple's keyboard layout and keep the order of these modifier keys the same. This is especially useful if you get confused switching between Apple and third-party keyboards.

[image: Mac change modifier keys]

> Consider enabling the checkbox for Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys if you have a third-party keyboard that shares media keys with function keys.

Comment: This is the best answer. Just a note for those of you who have blindspots like me:
There is a selection box at the top of this dialog to select what keyboard you are mapping! If you select the correct keyboard this tool works great. If you don't you won't think it works at all :(